# Windows 7: Is there a way to reroute CMD+Left to Pos1 and CMD+Right to End?

Tags: windows-7, windows, macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Using Mac OSX, I quickly grew accustomed to <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> to jump to the beginning or the end of the line in a text-editor. On my work-PC, these combinations only jump one word left or right, as <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd> or <kbd>right</kbd> to on the Mac.

Is there a way achieve these keybindings in Windows 7 too? The system preference for keyboard only lets me pick cursor speed and such nonsense.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/download/).

The CMD key translates to the Window key IIRC (I don't have a Mac keyboard handy).

Add this to the default script

```
#Right:: SendInput {End}
#Left:: SendInput {Home}
```

That will override the Window+Left,Right which snaps the window to the left and right side of the screen.

You can map the Aero Snap to something else, like Alt - Right,Left

```
!Right:: SendInput #{Right}
!Left:: SendInput #{Left}
```

Comment: Sounds good, I'll try this and give feedback soon. I tried Autohotkey before and found it pretty difficult to figure out even very simple things, but I'll try this.

Comment: surfasb, you're right about the Windows key. @Akku The locations of the modifier keys are different if you use a non-Apple keyboard. It might be worth it to buy one though.

Comment: why do you need to send `Home` and `End` keys why you can simply press the home/end on the keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> for begining of the line, or <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> for the end of the line (Home and End), which is close by the <kbd>Cmd</kbd> key.

EDIT: This will only work on the Apple Mac keyboards

Comment: Doesn't work on my machine's built in keyboard (DELL Studio). And besides, I'm using an external keyboard which doesn't feature an FN key.

Comment: Ahhh, sorry, didn't read that part that it's a different computer

Comment: PCs already have dedicated Home and End for this purpose although a few small laptops will map it to Fn+Left/Right